# Computer will not boot from DVD Drive or USB - Windows 10 restart loop

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb, dvd

**(I'm on Windows 10)**

OK, this is a very interesting problem which I have tried everything to solve. My computer is stuck in a restart loop. When I turn it on, it goes to "Preparing Automatic Repair" screen with the windows logo, and then the screen goes black and the computer restarts and again shows the preparing automatic repair screen.

Now I believe that I need to reload the operating system on my hard drive, **but here is the main issue: my computer will not fully boot from the DVD drive or USB.**

When I put, for example, a Win 7 OS DVD into the drive, the computer shows the loading bar for the DVD files, show the starting windows screen, gets to the blue "Starting" screen, and then restarts. When I try to boot from an Ubuntu USB, I get to the Ubuntu scree, I select "Try Ubuntu without installing", and the computer restarts.

---

### **What I have tried so far:**

- Disabling Fast Boot
- Disabling Secure Boot
- **Running Memtest - It was the only thing I could boot to and it showed no errors**

I have absolutely no idea what to do now. All of my searches on Google yield results of people with the "Advanced Options" button, which I am not able to get to. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power off. Pull the sata/power lead from the main windows drive. In the bios, change boot order to DVD first. Replace sata/power from drive and switch on. Hopefully you can now boot the DVD.

Comment: For clarification, after making DVD first, you want me to power off again and plug the HDD back in, then turn on the computer?

Comment: Thank you very much. I can now boot to DVD. I'm going to format the drive in an external environment and then load windows onto it.

Comment: Glad to help - It's one of the many annoying 'enhancements' of Windows 10